# Azure sql database TLS is always enable?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, tls1.2

- I wrote a java code. In the code, I used com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource to establish a JDBC connection with my Azure sql database . I found that no matter whether I used "  ds.setEncrypt(true);" or not, the JDBC connection was encrypted by TLS ( I use wireshark to catch the TCP packaege , all the package is TLS  whether I used "  ds.setEncrypt(true);" or not ).
- Why ? I checked many official documents, but I couldn't find the answer . It's too difficult...
- Azure sql database TLS is always enable ? Are there relevant official  documents to prove it ?
- The question is : I use  ds.setEncrypt(true) or not ,even i set this to "false" , the TCP packages are encrypted by TLS . Why ?
  Below is my code to establish the JDBC connection .

```
    public static Connection getConnectionObject() {
        SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
        ds.setServerName("azuresqldbserver0821.database.windows.net");
        ds.setDatabaseName("azuresqldb0821");
        ds.setPortNumber(1433);
        ds.setUser("root0817");
        ds.setPassword("<YourStrong@Passw0rd>");

        ds.setEncrypt(false);// I use this method or not ,even i set this to "false" , the TCP packages are encrypted by TLS
        ds.setTrustServerCertificate(true);
        Connection conn;
        try {
            conn = ds.getConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Comment: `I checked many official documents, but I couldn't find the answer . It's too difficult...` on the contrary, TLS1.2 is enabled by default for all clouds services and providers, as it should be, for several years now. You can't connect to AWS, Google or Azure without using HTTPS with at least TLS1.2. Major services started requiring TLS1.2 around 2015 and PCI-DSS requires this since 2020. All those changes were announced several months in advance, giving developers time to migrate their applications. At this point no cloud provider accepts unprotected connections to anything

Comment: What is the actual question anyway? Doesn't the connection work? Did you get an error?

Comment: But I use ds.setEncrypt(false) ,i can connect the Azure sql database successful . And  the TCP packages is encrypted by TLS , i am confused .

Comment: The question is I use  ds.setEncrypt(true) or not ,even i set this to "false" , the TCP packages are encrypted by TLS

Comment: The server may be configured to require encrypted connections, in which case the client settings are ignored. That's standard practice by now. In fact, recent *client* drivers enable encryption by default

Comment: If the code works, why are you trying to disable encryption? This may be a valid configuration eg in a Kubernetes or Docker cluster where the only connections allowed are from one container to another. That requires configuring the database server explicitly though. That's definitely not a valid scenario for cloud databases though

Comment: I just want to know why ...? It is better to have an official document to explain this situation : whether I use ds.setEncrypt(true) or not, the connection will be encrypted by TLS ....

Comment: Encryption in SQL Server is documented in the [SQL Server configuration docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-encrypted-connections-to-the-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16). For Azure SQL the options, how to check them and how to change them through the Azure Portal are explained in [the Azure SQL connectivity settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-settings?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal). Turns out AzureSQL allows lower TLS versions but recommends TLS1.2

Comment: You should also check the [Security overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/security-overview?view=azuresql) document which explains the various security rules, where and how encryption is used.

Answer (score 0):

When a client first attempts a connection to SQL Azure, it sends an initial connection request. Consider this a "pre-pre-connection" request. At this point the client does not know if TLS/SSL/Encryption is required and waits an answer from SQL Azure to determine if TLS/SSL is indeed required throughout the session (not just the login sequence, the entire connection session). A bit is set on the response indicating so. Then the client library disconnects and reconnects armed with this information.

When you set "Encrypt connection" setting on the connetion string you avoid the "pre-pre-connection", you are preventing any proxy from turning off the encryption bit on the client side of the proxy, this way attacks like man-in-the-middle attack are avoided.

When secure connections are needed, please enable "Encrypt connection" setting.

In-transit encryption to Azure SQL is always enabled.

Transport Layer Security (TLS) was previously known as Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).

Comment: But even if I use ds.setEncrypt(false)  , the TCP packages are encrypted by TLS . I don't know why

Comment: When you disable it what I described on the first paragragh will take place. That means a server side encryption will take place.

Comment: The docs explain why, and how to check the encryption settings. Encryption is used by default and can't be disabled by the client. The docs show how to check the database settings to find and change encryption settins

Comment: So I can only choose whether to verify the certificate sent to me by the server, but whether I verify the certificate or not, the connection is encrypted by TLS.

Comment: Exactly. If you don't set encryption true from the beginning you will be vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks, but still a server side encryption will be established. It is more secure to set encryption true from the start